# Access and copy an array of C structs in python ctypes

Tags: python, c++, sockets, ctypes

I have a nested C++ struct that I'm trying to send over to Python using UDP and get the values there.

```
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>

struct MyStruct {
    int intValue;
    float floatValue;
    // Add more members as needed

    struct MyInnerStruct {
        int intValue;
        float floatValue;
    };

    MyInnerStruct *InnerStruct;
};

int main() {

    MyStruct testStruct;
    testStruct.floatValue = 3.1;
    testStruct.intValue = 4;
    testStruct.InnerStruct = new MyStruct::MyInnerStruct[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        testStruct.InnerStruct[i].intValue = i + 23;
        testStruct.InnerStruct[i].floatValue = (i/10) + 23;
    
    }

    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize winsock." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    char hostname[256];
    char ip[100];

    // Get the hostname
    if (gethostname(hostname, sizeof(hostname)) == 0) {
        std::cout << "Hostname: " << hostname << std::endl;

        // Get the IP address
        struct hostent* host_info = gethostbyname(hostname);
        if (host_info != nullptr) {
            struct in_addr* address = reinterpret_cast<struct in_addr*>(host_info->h_addr);
            strcpy(ip, inet_ntoa(*address));
            std::cout << "IP Address: " << ip << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "Error getting host information." << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Error getting hostname." << std::endl;
    }
    int udpSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (udpSocket == -1) {
        perror("Error creating socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Server address
    sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(12345); // Choose a port
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip); // Replace with the server's IP

    // Serialize the struct into a byte stream
    char buffer[sizeof(MyStruct)];
    memcpy(buffer, &testStruct, sizeof(MyStruct));

    // Send the serialized struct over the UDP socket
    if (sendto(udpSocket, buffer, sizeof(MyStruct), 0, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&serverAddr), sizeof(serverAddr)) == -1) {
        perror("Error sending data");
        closesocket(udpSocket);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    std::cout << "Struct sent successfully." << std::endl;

    // Clean up
    closesocket(udpSocket);

    
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

But in Python I can't seem to get the values of the nested C++ struct.

```
import socket
import struct
from ctypes import *
# IP address and port number for server
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 12345

class MyInnerStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('field4', c_int),
        ('field5', c_float),
        
    ] 

class MyStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('field1', c_int),
        ('field2', c_float),
        ('field3', POINTER(MyInnerStruct)),
    ]

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((HOST, PORT))

while True:
   
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(sizeof(MyStruct))
    
    received_struct = cast(data, POINTER(MyStruct)).contents
  
   # Access the fields of the received struct
    field1 = received_struct.field1
    field2 = received_struct.field2
    field3 = received_struct.field3

    received_inner_struct = cast(field3, POINTER(MyInnerStruct)).contents

   

    for i in range(field1):
        array[i].field4 = field3[i].field4
        array[i].field5 = field3[i].field5   //these lines are not working    

# Close the socket
sock.close()
```

I tried accessing the values of the inner nested struct (in the for loop) by trying to de-reference but I couldn't.  How can I access `field4` and `field5` in the inner struct?

Comment: The struct contains a pointer.  `sizeof(MyStruct)` is the size of the int, float, and (assuming) 64-bit pointer which is 16.  It doesn't include memory pointed to by the pointer, and sending `MyStruct, sizeof(MyStruct)` is only going to send the `MyStruct` data including a pointer that won't be valid in another process.

Comment: Oh okay thank you for that info. Now how would you recommend I access that struct array pointer in python?

Comment: I suggest that you use protocol buffers ([protobuf](https://protobuf.dev/)), it's well supported by Python and C++.

Comment: Agree.  Without protobuf, you would have to manually serialize the all the fields on the C side and rebuild the memory on the Python side.

Comment: I am unable to use protobuf for my project. So I'll probably have to serialize the struct. But how do I serialize a nested struct in my case and interpret it in python?

Comment: Construct a buffer with field1-3, followed by fields4-5 for each array element.  I can show you the Python side of something like that but don't have access to a C compiler at the moment.

Comment: So the thing is I will eventually be sending out many structures like these. Meaning there will be many Structures with their own array of Structures. I'm failing to understand how its sent over sockets. I have a while loop packet listener in python but Once the first packet is received, I will have to read in the int value(field1) which will tell me the size of the array inside the structure. So you can show me python pseudo code if possible. I apologize in advance if this is very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, send the equivalent field1-3 followed by field4-5 for each array element.  Here's the Python equivalent I used for testing:

```py
import struct
import socket

# send field1=4, field2, and 4x the two fields of each array element.
data = struct.pack('<ififififif', 4, 3.5, 1, 1.25, 2, 2.5, 3, 2.75, 4, 3.00)

with socket.socket(type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as s:
    s.sendto(data, ('localhost', 5000))
```

One way to unpack, not overly efficient.  To receive, read the first two fields and initialize field1-2 of `MyStruct`.  Use `field1` to allocate an array of `MyInnerStruct`.  Then read the pairs of field4-5 from the buffer and initialize the array.  Finally, assign the array to `MyStruct.field3`:

```py
import socket
import struct
import ctypes as ct

class MyInnerStruct(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('field4', ct.c_int),
                ('field5', ct.c_float))
    def __repr__(self):  # for display
        return f'({self.field4}, {self.field5})'

class MyStruct(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('field1', ct.c_int),
                ('field2', ct.c_float),
                ('field3', ct.POINTER(MyInnerStruct)))
    def __repr__(self):  # for display
        return f'[{self.field1}, {self.field2}, {list(self.field3[:self.field1])})]'

sock = socket.socket(type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('', 5000))

data, addr = sock.recvfrom(40960)
field1, field2 = struct.unpack_from('<if', data)
received_struct = MyStruct(field1, field2)  # pointer is null at this point

inner_array = (MyInnerStruct * field1)()  # allocate inner array
start_of_inner = struct.calcsize('if')  # index data after MyStruct fields
size_of_inner = struct.calcsize('if')   # size of inner array element
index = start_of_inner
for i in range(field1):
    field4, field5 = struct.unpack_from('<if', data[index:])  # read fields of an array element
    inner_array[i] = MyInnerStruct(field4, field5) # assign to the array element
    index += size_of_inner
received_struct.field3 = inner_array  # pointer to the initialized inner array
print(received_struct)  # now print complete received item.
```

Run the receiver code to wait for a packet, then run the sender code to transmit the packet:

Output from receiver:

```
[4, 3.5, [(1, 1.25), (2, 2.5), (3, 2.75), (4, 3.0)])]
```

In fact, dropping `ctypes` may be faster and more simple by building Python class instances parsed from the data stream.  No need to deal with Python/C marshaling:

```py
import socket
import struct

class MyInnerStruct:
    _format = '<if'  # format and size of serialized data
    _size = struct.calcsize(_format)

    def __init__(self, f4, f5):
        self.field4 = f4
        self.field5 = f5

    @classmethod
    def from_data(cls, data):
        return cls(*struct.unpack_from(cls._format, data))

    @classmethod
    def from_data_array(cls, data, count):
        # construct a list of InnerStruct from data of known size
        return [cls(*struct.unpack_from(cls._format, data[n*cls._size:(n+1)*cls._size])) for n in range(count)]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'[{self.field4}, {self.field5}]'

class MyStruct:
    _format = '<if'  # format and size of serialized data
    _size = struct.calcsize(_format)

    def __init__(self, f1, f2):
        self.field1 = f1
        self.field2 = f2
        self.field3 = MyInnerStruct.from_data_array(data[self._size:], f1)

    @classmethod
    def from_data(cls, data):
        return cls(*struct.unpack_from(cls._format, data))
                       
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'[{self.field1}, {self.field2}, {self.field3}]'

sock = socket.socket(type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('', 5000))

data, addr = sock.recvfrom(40960)
received_struct = MyStruct.from_data(data)
print(received_struct)  # now print complete received item.
```

(same output)